# How to edit variables in html file loaded through iframe in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

I have a html file that I want to load into an `iframe` that is in a component. I want to be able to change information in the html file via a form (with the `useState` hook and `onChange` attribute). In the end I will have a button to copy the contents of the iframe.

```
<html>
 <div>
   content {changing content} content
 </div>
</html>
```

How do I establish states in my html file? so that I can change have access to it in my component?

I have tried utilizing `srcDoc` and just passing it through a variable: `let ans = ".....{statevar 1}..."` (i didn't use double quotes) `<iframe srcDoc={ans}></iframe>` which works, but when I copy the information it copies all the `div`s and other tags.

I am trying to copy the functionality of this website (https://csg.subaverage.site/) React and NextJS.

Comment: ...why? If you already control the content via React, why would you need an iframe? In fact, React's super power is "not having to care whether it's in a browser at all", React is already in control of the content.

Comment: The website that im trying to replicate utilizes an iframe. I don't have a preference but when I was trying to reverse engineer the process I saw it was being used. Definetly interested in hearing others ways to tackle the problem.